# Cloud FireStore array security rule based on array element id

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a document called `challenge` which has an array called `participants`. Each `participant` is basically a `user` document with some extra information like `score`, `reps` etc. I am using `arrayRemove(participant)` and `arrayUnion(updatedPartipant)` to replace basically update their score when they redo a challenge. I want to write a security rule that checks that the authenticated user uid matches the userId for the update (ie to stop one participant changing another score). Is it possible to write a security rule that says:

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid === request.data.id
```

or do I need to move this array to be a subcollection?

Comment: I think you will have a much easier time with this if you use a subcollection instead of an array.

Comment: According to this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) from the official docs the best way is to use subcollection.